Material UI Hover Text for Input fields
I'm using the Material UI controls in React such as these:

TextField
Switch
DateTimePicker
RadioGroup

Do they have a hover text property? I mean when you hover over the field, some helper text pops up.

All MUI components that wrap DOM nodes accept any attribute of the underlying DOM node. Sounds like you're looking for the native title attribute that shows a native browser tooltip on hover.
Example:
<TextField name="username" title="Enter Your Username" {...otherProps} />

If the native browser tooltip isn't good enough, you can also look at MUI's Tooltip component which can wrap any component and gives you more control over the tooltip's style.
Example:
<Tooltip placement="right" title="Enter Your Username">
  <TextField name="username" {...otherProps} />
</Tooltip>


Thanks. But this doesn't achieve my outcome. I'm looking for the classic hover text when I hover over the field.
This solution creates a separate icon beside the field with the hove text instead.

Please explain classic hover text. Do you mean Tooltip?

Actually, my mistake. I tried the  tag and it didn't do the job. But I realised you already gave the answer I was after before that. The "title" property is what I was looking for. Thankyou. :)
